# How to remove an image saved as wallpaper from lock screen on Android 4.4.2?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, wallpaper

Micromax Canvas 2 Colors with Android 4.4.2 is my first smartphone and I'm finding my way around slowly.

I saw an image on a website of Google Chrome and I clicked on the image and pressed save image. I got a message saying image downloading. Later, I opened the image from the gallery, did some size changes as requested, then made it my wallpaper for the lock screen. However, I am unable to remove the image now from the lock screen and go back to the default image.

Where is the image stored for me to go ahead and delete this image so that it goes back to the default option of the phone, when it allowed the default wallpaper in the screen and if I played an app called Saavan, it would put that albums image as the lock screen image automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Images downloaded from Chrome are stored in `/sdcard/download`. If you don't have an SD card, check in the internal memory's `/download` directory.

After finding the image, delete it and change your wallpaper either from settings -> display -> wallpaper or by pressing and holding on empty space on the home screen and then selecting wallpaper.

Answer (score -1):

Your wallpaper should be the same regardless of whether you're on the lockscreen or not — it's not an iPhone ;)

Changing your wallpaper on 4.4 is easy, you just press and hold in any empty space on your screen after unlocking your phone. Choose "Wallpapers" and select your wallpaper. You can either choose one of the default ones, or select "Pick image" to choose one from your gallery.

Comment: AFAIK most android flavors allow a lock screen and home wallpaper to be different

Answer (score -2):

Go to settings, wallpaper, lock screen and find or change the image there.